# Processing the same .NET assembly with two different obfuscators

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

Processing the same .NET assembly (feeding the output of one into the other as input) with two different obfuscators increases the chance to make decompilation impossible?

Thanks.

Comment: No, decompilation is never impossible.

Comment: I presume you're talking about feeding the output of one into the other as input, rather than having them both act on the original assembly?

Comment: @Damien: Yes, will try to improve my question.

Comment: This depends on obfuscators in question. If they both have the same set of features (say both rename private members to unreadable gibberlish) - you won't get any benefit of doing that twice. If the set of features is distinct - that might help. Of course it cannot make decompilation impossible, only harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompilation is never impossible. It may though quite easily get to the point where no current tools will do it all for you, so you can certainly increase the amount of manual reverse-engineering done.

Two tools that do roughly the same transformations to obfuscate code will have little or no effect over just using one. If however there's a lot of things each does that the other does not then it **might** make reverse-engineering harder.

Whether it helps or not the risk of the obfuscation introducing a bug due to a bug in the obfuscator always increases, and may be harder to trace if the buggy code has then been re-obfuscated.